# FBSDKCoreKit not found react-native version 0.30

Tags: ios, react-native, fbsdk

I'm trying to add facebook-login to my react-native 0.30 app (IOS). I have followed all steps in: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/ios/getting-started/ and the fbsdk worked in my previous apps, running on older react-native versions. Now I receive the error message 'FBSDCoreKit/FBSDCoreKit.h' file not found and facebook suggest following troubleshooting:

- Make sure that the Facebook SDK frameworks are installed in ~/Documents/FacebookSDK.
- Make sure that FBSDK[Core, Login, Share]Kit.framework show up in the Link Binary with Libraries section of your build target's Build Phases.
- Make sure that ~/Documents/FacebookSDK is in the Framework Search Path of your build target's Build Setting

I have checked all these steps but still it does not work. Any ideas? Thanks

---